Does Löwenheim-Skolem require Foundation in any way?
As title states, I'm curious whether Löwenheim-Skolem (in either of its upward or downward versions) necessitates some implicit use of Foundation. The usual presentation makes quite clear the reliance of LS on $\mathsf{AC}$ / Zorn's Lemma and as far as I've understood, LS itself is basically equivalent to $\mathsf{DC}$. Is there any reliance on Foundation throughout the proofs?

No, no foundation. They’re not equivalent to DC though. I think some weak version of DLST is, but the strongest phrasings of both are equivalent to full AC, if I recall correctly.

The statement that every infinite set admits a group is equivalent to AC: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12973/does-every-non-empty-set-admit-a-group-structure-in-zf

@Lucenaposition It depends exactly how you phrase LS. For example, "Every satisfiable first-order theory with an infinite model has arbitrarily large (= admitting an injection from a given set) models" doesn't give every set a group structure. In fact, ZF alone proves that every set injects into a group (just take the free group on the given set).

My formulation is "For every satisfiable first-order theory $T$ with an infinite model and every infinite set $S$, it is possible to make $S$ a model of $T$ (by adding the relations and predicates."

No, there is no use of the Axiom of Foundation in standard proofs of the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.
To see this, you could of course just read a proof and check for yourself.
But here's another way to see that the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem (like almost all theorems of mathematics outside of set theory) could not possibly depend on Foundation.
$\mathsf{ZFC-Foundation}$ proves that every set is in bijection with a well-founded set (indeed, with an ordinal). Hence (for any language $L$), any $L$-structure is isomorphic to one whose domain is well-founded. Thus, if an $L$-theory $T$ has infinite models, then it has infinite models in $\mathrm{WF}$, the class of well-founded sets. Thus, by Löwenheim-Skolem relativized to $\mathrm{WF}$, it has models of arbitrary infinite cardinalities.
This kind of meta-argument shows that any theorem which is provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and is "isomorphism invariant" is in fact provable in $\mathsf{ZFC-Foundation}$.
